# Radio Style But with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to make something like a radio style buttons, but no text, just images. Something like this is what i want to style below. And i want to make it so that on the click its a certain image. But i want it to send out a value like a radio button html coding would.

How should i go about coding this or is there any tips or anything i should follow? Just not sure how to approach it.

Basically i want something that would work like radio buttons but in the theme below.

[image: Style I want]

Comment: I tried just styling radio buttons but it didnt work well for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd use jQuery. Add an onclick to each "radio" (div with a class radio) to run a function which removes the "selected" class from all the divs and adds it to the one clicked.

Example at: http://jsfiddle.net/dGWJp/

If you need to retrieve data from the radios, give each radio div a `data-value="valuehere"` as per HTML5 spec (works in older HTML too!), find the selected div with jquery and then get the 'data-value' attribute from there.

Set one to have the `selected` as well as `radio` at the beginning to force a selection.

Comment: Yeah im just trying to get a feel to start for how to code this then i can do it! Thanks :D

Comment: An example would be awesome :)

Comment: @soniccool What have you tried so far?  This answer explains *exactly* what to do.  Stack Overflow isn't meant to be a "giev me the codez" site; it's meant to give advice on the best solution to a problem.

Comment: Oh no im trying to style with radio buttons but its not working out in the best way for me. Plus im trying to make an image stay over it when its clicked.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle I haven't given an exact solution, just helped give an idea of how to use jQuery to this effect. If you're starting out with jQuery all the functions can be very daunting and its difficult to know where to start!

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what i was looking for. Yeah i like to learn but this is definitely going to help me. So far im just fluent in html

Comment: If i desire different images over ever field should i just place that in css? Or should i do it another way?

Comment: Yeah, just change the CSS but bare in mind the background settings do not print. In that case, you could change the javascript to change the contents as well/ instead of the class.

Comment: Yeah i got it, and to specify a default selected one i tried adding `checked="checked"` but it didnt work in the field.

Comment: Oh i see you wrote it in the post to select one to force a selection

Comment: How do i specify something like this in these boxes `<input id="version" name="version" type="radio" value="Verizon" checked="checked" />` This i cant figure out. Also im confused on how to make one of them default?

Comment: `class="checked radio"` means checked, `class="radio"` means unchecked. `value="Verizon"` could be replaced by `data-value="Verizon"` on each div. You can retrieve the value using some jQuery to find the one with the "checked radio" class and then use the jQuery `attr` method (google this) to get the `data-value`. Its important to remember these are not radio buttons: they are JavaScript and div *pretending* to be radios.